# How can a component respond to an action?

Tags: ember.js

tl;dr: **Data can be sent in and out of a component, but I only know how to send actions out. Is there a way to send actions in?**

---

In my Ember application, I have something like the following UI from Google Maps:

[image]

The background map corresponds to a PinsRoute/PinsView/PinsController, and it shows many pins. When you click one, you enter the `PinRoute`, which renders the overlay to `{{outlet}}`. Both the big map and the thumbnail (in the Google Maps image, the picture that says "Street View") are components: `FullscreenMapComponent` and `ThumbnailMapComponent`, respectively.

In Google maps, when you click "Street view", it pans and zooms the main map to the selected point. This is essentially what I'm trying to figure out how to wire up.

When the user clicks "streeth view" on my `ThumbnailMapComponent`, I can send out an action, which the `PinsRoute` can handle. The question is, how can I then reach down to my `FullscreenMapComponent` and invoke the appropriate method (`.panToSelected()`, in this case)?

Comment: Sorry but this has been bugging me - where does it say "Street View" in your screenshot?

Comment: the first image in the detail panel, top-left of screen

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a good solution. Have the component register itself to whatever controller it's being rendered in, and that way you can access the component in action handlers.

In my case, I added a method to my component

```
App.FullscreenMapComponent = Ember.Component.extend({

  ...

  _register: function() {
    this.set('register-as', this);
  }.on('init')

});
```

and a property to my controller:

```
App.SensorsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({

  fullscreenMap: null,

  ...

});
```

In my template, I bind the two with my new `register-as` property:

```
// sensors.hbs

  {{fullscreen-map data=mapData
    selectedItem=currentSensor
    action='selectSensor'
    deselect='deselectSensor'
    register-as=fullscreenMap }}
```

And now, let's say I click the thumbnail above and it sends an action that bubbles up to my `ApplicationRoute`, I can now do this:

```
// ApplicationRoute.js

actions: {
  panTo: function(latLong, zoom) {
    this.controllerFor('sensors').get('fullscreenMap').panTo(latLong, zoom);
  }
}
```

Presto! Components responding to actions.

### Update (10/6/2016)

Whew, I've learned a lot in two years.

I would no longer recommend this solution. In general, you should strive for your components to be declarative, and have their output and behavior depend solely on their state. Instead, my original answer here solved the problem using an imperative method, which is brittle, harder to understand, and not very easy to extend (what if we wanted to tie the the map's position to the URL?).

If I was refactoring this specific component, I'd probably make `{{fullscreen-map}}` accept `latLong` and `zoom` params. If someone from the outside sets those, the map would respond and update itself. You can use `didReceiveAttrs` from within the component to respond to param changes, and then from there call the imperative `panTo` method from Google's API.

The takeaway is that, even if you have to interact with imperative methods (maybe because of a third-party lib), strive to make your own components' APIs as declarative as possible. What first seems like "sending an action down" can usually be expressed as some function of state, and that state is what you want to identify and make explicit.

Answer (score 1):

This is working example but I am not 100% sure that this approach is best

Here what you can do:

When calling action pass your component as parameter:

```
App.PinController = Ember.Controller.extend({
   actions: {
      actionThatComponentCalls: function(){
         // different component will be called
         new App.MyOtherComponent().send('differentAction'):
      }
   }
});

App.FullScreenMapComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
   click: function(){
     this.sendAction();
   }
});

App.MyOtherComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
   actions: {
     differentAction: function(){
       console.log('different action called');
     }
   }
});
```

Hope this helps

Comment: The problem is the component that I want to respond to the action is not the one generating it, it's a different component (from a different route).

Comment: Thanks for your help! Now, what if `MyOtherComponent` is being instantiated in my HBS template?